# Any payment gateway in India which can auto charge customer on renewals?

Tags: invoices, payments

I am running a monthly subscription based business, When renewal is due, We call customers and they make the payment.

Is there any way, I can charge my customers automatically like the subscription in paypal ?  (As paypal cant be used in India, When both the buyers & sellers are from India)

Can you please suggest some way to achieve the automatic charging ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't sound like a freelancing-specific question, but a question that could apply to any business. You could try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) though!

Comment: Does the Indian banking system allow for regular payments to be set up between accounts? Here in the UK we call them Standing Orders; there may be a local equivalent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about freelancing, but payment services

Answer (score 1):

Check [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). If you don't want to program, you can use [Typeform](http://www.typeform.com/) since they have an integration.

Comment: Careful; Stripe is [not supported](https://stripe.com/global) in India. That is, while an Indian customer can pay via Stripe, one cannot pay an Indian company via Stripe.

Answer (score 1):

Try Razorpay, If your business is registered and has GSTIN Number.

Razorpay takes cut per transaction for processing each payment.

Case study: Hotstar uses it.

Answer (score 1):

As told above, you can use PayPal for international payments, however, in the context of India I do think that Razorpay is best. Don't know but I think Instamojo also does offer these kinds of services.